# Two questions from ring homomorphisms.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ring-homomorphism

1. What is natural homomorphism $f\colon \Bbb C[x]\to \Bbb C[x,x^{-1}]$? Is it just embedding?
2. Are all prime ideals in $\Bbb C[x,x^{-1}]$of the form $\{\,g: g(y)=0\,\}$ for chosen points $y$?? Of course, sets of its elements which take value $0$ in chosen point are prime and maximal ideals, but are there more ideals or no? If natural homomorphism is embedding then there shouldn't be more ideals because counterimage of any prime ideal in $\Bbb C[x,x^{-1}]$ is prime in $\Bbb C[x]$, and embedding is 1-1. Am I right?

Comment: Actually, I'd call the homomorphism in 1 canonical rather than natural

Comment: Hint. Use that $\Bbb C[x,x^{-1}]$ is a localization of $\Bbb C[x]$.

Comment: user26857 only lecture we had only defined and constructed localisation but nothing more was said about it.

Comment: Ok, I read on wikipedia. So ideal generated by (x-y) goes to ideal generated by the same, right? All ideals in localisation are of the same form as in C[x]?